# how would I count the number of returns in my list and include it in my printed statement?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, count

```
for phrase in states_of_america:
  words = phrase.split()
  try:
    if words[0].upper().startswith("A"):
     print(phrase)
  except IndexError:
    pass
```

thats my code currently, I want to be able to print the number of states than return with selected letter for example There are 5 states beginning with A, Alabama, Arkansas, Arizona and Alaska

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you know how to increment a numeric variable?

Comment: I do not I shall look it up

Comment: Without necessary tags, your question won't reach the target audience.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a counter. And add one extra print statement with information how many countries there are (counter value)

```
counter = 0
for phrase in states_of_america:
  words = phrase.split()
  try:
    if words[0].upper().startswith("A"):
     print(phrase)
     counter++
  except IndexError:
    pass
print('Number of states that start with "A" is', counter)
```